# Running a task on Service worker offline on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am developing a PWA on AngularJS. I am using service worker to make to work offline as well. I have implemented a method on service worker called alarm() which has a setTimeout function which shows a notification at a set interval. 
My problem is that this works fine on desktop and also when I connect my Android phone and run it on Android phone using Chrome remote devices. It works fine on desktop browser and shows notifications, but it does not work on phone when I access the site from the HTTPS source.

serviceWorker.js

sync:

```js
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  if (event.tag == "sync") {
    event.waitUntil(alarm());
    console.log("sync fired!!");
  }
});
```

alarm function:

```js
//shows a notification every minute
function alarm(){
  console.log('running:');
  setTimeout(function(){
    alarm();
    self.registration.showNotification("Alert!");
  }, 1*60*1000);
}
```

Thank you.